# Match all after nth occurrence of specified character

Tags: regex

I have a localization file that I need to edit, but there are two thousand lines, and I'd rather not do this by hand.

Each line is formatted like this: `"abc" = "123";` and I need to replace whatever is in place of `123`.

What I want it to do is match everything after the third `"`.

I've tried multiple combinations like `(?:[^"]*"){3}`, and variations of `^[.^"]"*[^"]"*[^"]"*` but they do not produce what I need.

So in this example:

```
"abc" = "123";
"def" = "456";
"ghi" = "789";
```

`123";`,`456";`, and`789";` should be matched.

Comment: What's your question about it? If you don't know how to write a regular expression, read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info. If you do, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it. SO is not a tutoring service or free code-writing service.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter before finishing writing this post.

Comment: Your first regexp should work if you anchor it to the beginning of the line with `^`.

Comment: It actually matches all before the third `"`. I want everything _after_ the third `"` to be matched and nothing before.

Comment: Add `(.*)` after it to capture everything after the match.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to only match the part *within* the quotes, excluding the final `";`?

Comment: Actually, yes I would, trincot. I don't know how I didn't think to do that initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose this:

```
[^"]*(?=";)
```

This only matches the part *within* quotes, excluding (but requiring) the ending `";`.

See demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dV4nE3/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will capture anything between the last quotes

```
" = "(.*)";$
```